# Building app for Redmi 4 returns error

Tags: android, android-studio, build, redmi-device

When I build my app for the phone Xiomi Redmi 4 it shows an error, asking to uninstall the previous app data. But I built the app for the first time.

Error:

> Installation failed with message Failed to establish session. It is
>   possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing
>   version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.  WARNING:
>   Uninstalling will remove the application data!  Do you want to
>   uninstall the existing application?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to developer options in settings and disable MIUI optimizations. It'll ask you to reboot and it should work after that.